# Converting Matlab function (mscript) to simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I wrote a M function (Mscript), but sadly I cannot use this function directly in my model (not even as Matlab function block), because of the TargetLink restrictions.

if there any way I can convert the function to a simulink model or do I have to do it from the scratch?

Comment: AFAIK there is no automatic way of doing this. Either you modify the function to support code generation and TargetLink restrictions, or you have to re-implement it from scratch in Simulink.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, I did my fair part of research. Couldn't come across anything. Took a shot, thinking maybe there will be some community developed tool, which will achieve what I wanted.

Comment: Can you declare your function as "extrinsic" and call from MATLAB Function block?

Comment: @Navan, I cannot use the Matlab Function block. TargetLink has it's own libraries and Matlab Function block is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of targetlink does support the function block in simulink models.

An alternative to actual simulink blocks might be a stateflow chart. Targetlink is limited to the action language c, but still rewriting it in a stateflow function in c might be closer to the original m code than converting it to blocks.